# How to calculate if the between-subject variability is significant given repeated measurements?

Tags: statistical-significance, repeated-measures

I have a question that's been bothering me research wise. The situation is as follows:

> We are measuring a quantity in
>   subjects for which we assume that it
>   differs significantly between
>   subjects, which we would like to
>   prove. For each subject we have 2
>   measurements of this quantity at two
>   different times (time difference
>   between measurements is not the same
>   for each subject). How would I show
>   that the variability of the quantity
>   between subjects can not be explained
>   by the measurement variability?

The data I have is based on voxel data, so I have for an ROI a mean and standard deviation per measurement, two measurements per subject and 50 subjects.

Comment: First I dont think you "assume" what you are trying to prove. Your hypothesis should look like null hypothesis Ho: No change between subjects vs. H1: there is a change between subjects.